# bat file to copy column data to another column in csv

Tags: batch, batch-file, csv

My csv file contain 6 columns and I want to copy 6th column value inside first column path value.

```
Path,Firstname,Lastname,Name,Description,Images  
C:\Users\magoo\abc.jpg,alex,ross,pvs,data,123.jpg  
C:\Users\magoo\pqr.jpg,kris,ward,poi,data,784.jpg
```

Output I am looking for

```
Path,Firstname,Lastname,Name,Description,Images  
C:\Users\magoo\123.jpg,alex,ross,pvs,data,123.jpg  
C:\Users\magoo\784.jpg,kris,ward,poi,data,784.jpg
```

I only want to only replace image name from first path column with 6th column value.
Kindly help as I am stuck here since long.I am using copy commands but it is replacing entire text from column one.

Code I tried:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
( FOR /f "tokens=1-6delims=," %%a IN (ImportFile.csv) DO ( 
   ECHO(%%a%%f,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f ) 
)>new.csv
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: After having changed from [SO] without commas, it is still no csv file. Did you take a look at the [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) command in the meantime? It **is** important to know what separates the columns in the real file - not a nice screen representation.

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1-6delims=," %%a IN (ImportFile.csv) DO (
 ECHO(%%a%%f,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f
)
)>new.csv

GOTO :EOF

Comment: With this code I am able to append new image name to path but I want to remove old image name from that path.

Comment: For now I added your code to the question, please do that yourself in future instead of putting vital information in comments where it is hardly readable  without line breaks. Hint the `~dp` tilde modifiers allow to strip name extension information from a full qualified file name.

Comment: In your `echo` line, instead of `%%a%%f` do `%%~dpa%%f`.

Comment: Since you have tried something on your own now, you should have edited your [original question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57908674)...

Comment: It is working but it is combining my headers as well.I used skip=1 but now it is not printing my headers.I want headers the way it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote this and it stripped my comments.
.. then I fixed a bug :(

```
@echo off

Set Input_file=test.csv
Set Output_file=test_modified.csv

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%l in (%Input_file%) do call :process_tokens "%%l" "%%m" "%%n" "%%o" "%%p" "%%q"
goto :EOF

:process_tokens 
Set Col2=%~2
Set Col3=%~3
Set Col4=%~4
Set Col5=%~5
Set Col6=%~6

Set Col1=%~dp1%Col6%
echo %Col1%,%Col2%,%Col3%,%Col4%,%Col5%,%Col6% >>%Output_file%

goto :EOF
```

I am using label/functions to accomplish this.

In the ":process_tokens" function, look at the %~dp2%Col6% line.

%~dp1 means:

- %~ = get the passed parameter and strip quotes from it.
- dp = drive and path only (aka strip the filename)
- 1  = passed param #1

%Col6% is where I tack on the filename you are looking for.

Comment: Also, @magoosh.. you posted while I was typing.  I didn't copy you ;)  Great minds think alike.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Data is coming correctly but it is copying headers as well.

Comment: @magoosh The call isn't necessary, in **your** code simply use `echo %%~dpa%%f,...`

Comment: @LotPings, no, the call isn't needed.  it just makes the code more readable and who doesn't love functions?

Comment: That's debatable, a call involves a 2nd hidden cmd, parameter passing etc, in sum it creates overhead and slows things down, when working with larger files this **could** be prohibitive.

Comment: @LotPings, `call` does **not** involve another `cmd` instance (if that is what you meant), but I agree, `call` is notably slower since the batch file is scanned for the called label for every single call...

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I am getting output like this C:\Users\magoo\"123.jpg",alex,ross,pvs,data,123.jpg . I want to remove double quotes.Kindly help

Comment: I don't have this happening in my tests.  I don't even see how it is possible.. this line->Set Col6=%~6  The tilde says to strip the quotes from the incoming param.  Is it quoted in your CSV file too?  If so, just take the quotes off of "%%q"..  I added them in the first place so it would work with filenames with a space in them.